# XMLHttpRequest send() from local file failed

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I want to load JSON file from a local file in my computer and I already downloaded Node.js and launched it. but it keeps showing this message "Failed to load... Cross origin requests are only supported for...."

also F12 showed me the file in line ourRequest.send();

this is my code...

```
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
var tajweedContainer=document.getElementById("rule_info");
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){

var ourRequest= new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET','testjson.json');
ourRequest.onload=function(){
var ourData=JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    renderHtml(ourData);
}
ourRequest.send();

});
function renderHtml(data){
    var htmlString="";
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        htmlString="<p>"+data[i].surah+data[i].ayah+"the grammar ";
       for(var ii=0;ii<data[i].annotations;ii++){
           htmlString+=data[i].annotations.end[ii]+data[i].annotations.rule[ii]+data[i].annotations.start[ii]

    }
htmlString+=".</p>";
tajweedContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',htmlString)

}

};
```

Comment: open the page from a node local server and serve the json file from that same server instance

Comment: you mean i open node and write http-server "file location"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make HttpRequest to local resources.

You need to provide this json file in your localhost server.

For example, your `testjson.json` should be accessible via `http://localhost/testjson.json` and then make an HTTP request to this endpoint

This code works properly here with me, the `console.log(data);` in renderHtml() are returning the `testjson.json`

```
<button id="btn">Render</button>
<div id="rule_info"></div>

<script>
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var tajweedContainer=document.getElementById("rule_info");

btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
var ourRequest= new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET','http://localhost/testjson.json');
ourRequest.onload=function(){
var ourData=JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    renderHtml(ourData);
}
ourRequest.send();

});
function renderHtml(data){
    console.log(data);

    var htmlString="";
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        htmlString="<p>"+data[i].surah+data[i].ayah+"the grammar ";
       for(var ii=0;ii<data[i].annotations;ii++){
           htmlString+=data[i].annotations.end[ii]+data[i].annotations.rule[ii]+data[i].annotations.start[ii]

    }
htmlString+=".</p>";
tajweedContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',htmlString)

}

};
</script>
```

Comment: i did what you said but it showed me this error "GET http://localhost/testjson.json 0 ()
(anonymous) @ jsTajweed.js:11" which the line contain ourRequest.send();

Comment: if you type `localhost/testjson.json` in your browser you could access it?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/testjson.json>>>>> i can access with this link but when i pasted in my code it gave this error "Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8080/testjson.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: `Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` usually is the local file system `file:///`, ensure you access your HTML page via `http://`